# Multiple Dockerfiles failure at building images in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to create a docker compose in order to eliminate the number of commands needed to run my tests. My goal is to run ONE command and it will start my containers and run my tests. It's my first time creating a docker compose file so please be patient. The docker-compose.file is located next to the other two dockerfiles. Below is the docker-compose that I have initiated, but I can't even build the images. I have tried to specify path buy adding " volumes: -.:. " but it still does not work.

```
services:
      headless-chrome:
        build: ./Dockerfile-headless-chrome
      dev-server:
        build: ./Dockerfile
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 118, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 926, in up
    scale_override=parse_scale_args(options['--scale']),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 401, in up
    svc.ensure_image_exists(do_build=do_build)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 311, in ensure_image_exists
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 888, in build
    buildargs=build_args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 137, in build
    raise TypeError("You must specify a directory to build in path")
TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
version: "3"
```

---

In order to run the tests I use to do this:
Shell 1:

```
$ SCHEME=http ENV=stage DOCKER_DEV_ENTRYPOINT='"npm run dev-server"' make docker-dev
```

When this is running, I need to run the below in a new shell (shell 2):

```
$ docker build -t headless-chrome -f Dockerfile-headless-chrome .
$ docker run -it --rm --net=host --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN headless-chrome /bin/bash
```

Then when Im inside the container Im running:

```
$ npm run selenium-docker
$ npm run uat
```

Comment: Don't put the name of your Dockerfile (e.g. Dockerfile-headless-chrome) to its path. Just `build ./`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path`

When you add `build: ./Dockerfile-headless-chrome` to your docker-compose.yml, you are setting the context folder, and not the Dockerfile file. The attribute you want is *build -> dockerfile*:

```
  services:
    headless-chrome:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
    dev-server:
      build: .
```

For `dev-server` I am not setting anything because it will use the default (`context: .` and `dockerfile: Dockerfile`). Actually, you also don't need the `context: .` at the headless-chrome, because it is the default.

[Docker Compose reference - build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build)

**Edited - Part 2**

There is also a problem at the command. For it to be automated, you have to change your `/bin/bash`.

Create a file for all your tests (entrypoint.sh):

```
npm run selenium-docker
npm run uat
```

Add this file to your image (`ADD`) and run it on start the container (`CMD`).

```
# Dockerfile

... your commands

ADD entrypoint.sh
CMD bash entrypoint.sh
```

And it is ready. Build again `docker-compose build` (because you edited the Dockerfile) and run `docker-compose up`

Comment: Thanks! I tried the above solution. But I receive another issue: WARNING: Image for service headless-chrome was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Recreating yetiui_dev-server_1 ...
Recreating yetiui_dev-server_1
Creating yetiui_headless-chrome_1 ...
Recreating yetiui_dev-server_1 ... done
Attaching to yetiui_headless-chrome_1, yetiui_dev-server_1
headless-chrome_1  | /bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
yetiui_headless-chrome_1 exited with code 2
yetiui_dev-server_1 exited with code 0

Comment: You need to specify a command for `/bin/bash`. If you don't want to run any command then you can leave it altogether and just run

`docker run -it --rm --net=host --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN headless-chrome`

Comment: @Rafael, thanks! The tests do run now, a small problem that exists is that it does not seem to wait until the dev-server is up running. I tried to add depends_on: dev-server, but it does not feel like it has an effect. It seems like dev-server exits with code 0 before my selenium is up.

Comment: Nice that it is working fine :). Now it is up to you. You need to make your application resilient to those failures. I like to use the wait-for-it script, but there are other options. Check [Controlling startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more information.

Comment: Alright! I'll take a look at it! I have taken a look at the contorlling startup order, but those attempts try to do a while loop until dev server is up. My issue is slightly different, my dev server is up and then immediately exits so even though my worker server tries to connect to it it wil lfail because dev has already exited.

Comment: @Rafael Do you mean of the `Dockerfile-alternate` alternative-docker-path?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari no. `context: .` is the alternative docker path. The `dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate` is the alternative Dockerfile.